# Why is my href not working in Django Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, href

I'm working on a method for a user to be able to make posts on my Django site project, the user should only be able to click on the button/link if they are logged in. I have tested it out multiple times and can't understand why I won't direct me to the page I specified I don't know what the problem is as I don't get an error.

Here is my URL's.py file:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from users.views import login_view, logout_view, register_view
from blog.views import post_create_view, home_view
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout' ),
    path('', login_view, name='login'),
    path('post-create/', post_create_view, name='post_create_view'),
    path('home', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', register_view, name='register')

]
```

Here is the html for the button/href text:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Top 'create post' bar -->
        <div class="create-post-bar d-lg-none col-lg-7 offset-lg-1">
            <p><a href="{% url 'post_create_view' %}">Create post</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my forms.py file:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'image'

        ]
```

Here is my views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import PostForm
from django.views.generic import ListView
from users.models import Profile_Create


# Create your views here.

def post_create_view(request):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        author = Profile_Create.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
        obj.author = author
        obj.save()
        form = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form' : form
        }

        return render(request, 'post_create_view.html', context)



def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        "posts" : BlogPost.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: It says something like "*view didn't return an HttpResponse object, it returned None*"? :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm sorry i don't understand, is that the error?

Comment: Make sure the paths to all the files you are rendering (home.html, etc.) are all correct. According to your code home.html must be present in the same directory as which your application was launched.